# How to disable Babel integration in Jest?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, jestjs

I have project which has code targeting both browser and node. It has `.babelrc` file for the browser code. But when I'm running tests for the node code using Jest it always reads the `.babelrc` file which is not required.

So I can somehow disable it?

Answer (score 6):

You need to create an additional jest setting file for your node test. In this file set `transform` to an empty object. To use this file you need to call jest with the `--config` option pointing to your node jest setting.